# How to implement VoIP + SIP in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sip, voip

I want to develop a VoIP application for iPhone .

But I don't know the basics of VoIP concepts and also if there are any sources or library available that can I use in my application .

So if anyone can provide me VoIP learning resources or library or anything that is useful in terms of VoIP and iPhone it will be precious to me .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it's still relevant: use [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org) . It's a SIP library written in C. You must compile the source for iphone, it is described in the docs [here](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started). After that take a look at a very basic sample application [here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm). It isn't very hard to use even if you don't know C, or how to compile libraries. Which was my case.

**UPDATE** Please be aware that pjsip uses GPL license.

Comment: hey can you please tell us what are consequences of using GPL license.

Comment: The source code under GPL which is legally incompatible with the Apple Store
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/no-gpl-apps-for-apples-app-store/8046

Answer (score 10):

Another option is [Twilio Client which has an iOS SDK](http://www.twilio.com/api/client/sdk). With Twilio you don't have to maintain any of the telephony infrastructure.

(I worked at Twilio)

Comment: For the record Twilio recently reduced their price for Client. It is now $0.0025 (1/4 cent) per minute. https://www.twilio.com/client/pricing

Comment: Hi, We have been working on twillo , we have implemented calling feature but it is always saying "Welcome to twillo you have to upgrade your account " and nothing else it is not making calls

Answer (score 2):

> I think you should check my answer in this link.

[iOS: Open Source VoIP/SIP Objective-C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/ios-open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code)

Also check

[SIP library for iOS with non-GPL license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854442/sip-library-for-ios-with-non-gpl-license)

> You can also try OZeki,SIphone etc

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper to handle calls in iOS Apple Standard library CallKit [Apple Documentation - CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit)

There is one lecture about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/230/) WWDC 2016

And, there is a tutorial in Ray Wenderlich [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios)

You still might need some library to handle SIP connections and handle incoming calls.

Open source library [linphone](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone)

Paid library [voipsipsdk](https://voipsipsdk.com)

Comment: Wrong - at least CallKit is only responsible for UI, to integrate an application to the native Call UI. The developer is still responsible for the implementation of voice transmission.

Comment: Thanks @T.Meyer I’m gonna update the answer.