# SIP library for iOS with non-GPL license

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sip, voip

Are there any non-GPL SIP libraries/SDKs that'll let me implement SIP for iOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the ones I know about:

**Proprietary:**

- [vaxvoip](http://www.vaxvoip.com/)

**Open source: GPL/LGPL**

- [sofia-sip](http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/development.html)
- [linphone](http://www.linphone.org)
- [exosip](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/exosip/)

Answer (score 3):

[oSIP](http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/) is **LGPL** and therefore can be used (as a library) in commercial and closed-source projects. It compiles easily for arm. It is the SIP library used by linphone for iPhone; however, linphone is GPL.

Comment: Could you give an example how to compile it for arm? Where do I specify the architecture? I just compiled it on mac os x but of course  an ios project can't use the lib.

Comment: Pretty old thread, but here is a link with [xcode project for osip/eXosip/c-ares](http://sip.antisip.com/xcode/xcode-exosip.tar.gz) - minor change to the project may be required over various osip/exosip versions!

Comment: You have to [do a lot](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2013/08/the-problem-with-using-lgpl-v2-1-code-in-an-ios-app/) in order to use an LGPL library in iOS app.

Answer (score -1):

These days SIP over WebRTC is getting popularity. It uses SIP Signaling and WebRTC as Media which is provided by google.

Following options are also very good if you to avoid getting into SIP level complexities.

https://alqatech.com/services/webrtc-sdk-android/

https://alqatech.com/services/webrtc-sdk-ios/

Comment: Doesn't appear to be open source.