# PJSIP - doesn't work out of the box in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, pjsip

We want to experiment with PJSIP for iPhones.  So we did a checkout of the code.  As soon as we open it up in Xcode 4.6.2, we see a lot of red errors.  Example errors include:

```
Expected property attribute before string
Autorelease pool undeclared
etc...
```

Every source file has red errors of this nature.

We're building for ios 6 devices.  All these errors are happening right out of the box before we even do anything.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that PJSIP is licensed using the GPL and [places restrictions on closed source distribution](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/FAQ#proprietary). If you're aware, all is well :)

Comment: Also, [iOS is not on the list of supported platforms](http://www.pjsip.org/sip_media_features.htm#platforms).

Comment: @Joachim thank you, do you have a recommendation on a SIP library for ios development?  Let's say our intention is to build a business offering voip services to customers

Comment: THe reason i looked at pjsip was because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/ios-open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code

Comment: Sorry, my VoIP days were before the iPhone :) I can only point to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10894326/477878).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson pointed to an old link regarding supported platforms. The current one is https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/PJSIP-Datasheet

Comment: So you were following https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone and got stuck? Which step exactly? It does not mention loading it in XCode, it uses the command line tools.