# SIP SDK for iOS

Tags: call, sip, voip, sip-server

I have SIP server, I want to implement a VoIP iOS application.
Is there any SIP SDK for iOS (Paid or free) that gives me the option to use any SIP server ?

thank you

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SIP library for iOS with non-GPL license](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854442/sip-library-for-ios-with-non-gpl-license)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the answers to these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854442/sip-library-for-ios-with-non-gpl-license) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/ios-open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code). The Google search that had these results was a search for "SIP SDK iOS"