# Making and Receiving Calls in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am making a Chat application . In that I want add facility like making and receiving calls.

There's an API called Twilio Client,But its chargeable.

Does anyone know any Free available API For it..

Thanks In advance.

Comment: by calls you mean internet calls? voip?

Comment: Yes before some months i have seen one API...but now i forgot...let me do some R & D.

Comment: Please give me your email id i will mail you.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith : I want any API that makes calls like **SKYPE**..

Comment: @iDroidDeveloper : it will be beneficial to all. So please reply here.

Comment: but actually i need some r & d ...I think I have code at my home...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For voip on iphone
Check the following http://www.pjsip.org/ Its open source

Also please search for stack overflow for voip + iphone
There are plenty of resources about it

Like this one
[How to implement VoIP + SIP in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558302/how-to-implement-voip-sip-in-iphone)