# iOS app with SIP concept to connect with server

Tags: objective-c, swift, sip, voip

I am trying to build an iOS app with SIP concept. I need to register with server and make both incoming and outgoing calls. So I go through this [document](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#Features). I completed **Building preparation** step. Then, I started next **Building PJSIP** step. Already I downloaded **PJSIP Source** from [this.](http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm)

Downloaded file name : `pjproject-2.4`

One of the sub folders : `pjsip`

List of pjsip's sub folder : No **dir** found.

I don't know how to execute this statement **"$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir"** in terminal.

What I did in terminal:

```
$ cd /Users/abc_123/Downloads/pjproject-2.4
```

---

I don't understand that line `/path/to/your/pjsip/dir`,So simply drag the `pjproject-2.4` file to terminal.

Next, If I tried second statement (for iPhone 5), 
**$ ARCH='-arch armv7s' ./configure-iphone && make dep && make clean && make** from [here](http://www.xianwenchen.com/blog/2014/06/09/how-to-make-an-ios-voip-app-with-pjsip-part-1/)

Terminal showing like this:

```
-bash: ./configure-iphone: Permission denied
```

I don't know how to execute this. Kindly guide me.

I have searched all the following documents. [iOS: Open Source VoIP/SIP Objective-C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/ios-open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code), [How to implement VoIP + SIP in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558302/how-to-implement-voip-sip-in-iphone/25154308#25154308)

Is there any coding wise tutorial, that how to connect Objective C or Swift with **SIP** and **VoIP** or SDK or API? I am very new to this concept. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Permission denied is the problem that you are not running command from root

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the file is not executable.

Try to excecute `chmod -x configure-iphone` in terminal to solve this problem.

Answer (score -2):

I have worked on same issue you must try with following, may it work for you and use the forum for query.

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#Commonproblems

Code Source (library) https://github.com/pzion/miumiu/tree/master/iPhone

Best,