# Trying to connect iOS app with SIP

Tags: ios, objective-c, sip, voip

I am doing an iOS app with SIP and VoIP concept. I don't know even basics.
So I referred following documents.

1.http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#Features

2.http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm

3.http://www.xianwenchen.com/blog/2014/06/09/how-to-make-an-ios-voip-app-with-pjsip-part-1/

4.[iOS: Open Source VoIP/SIP Objective-C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493050/ios-open-source-voip-sip-objective-c-code)

5.[How to implement VoIP + SIP in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558302/how-to-implement-voip-sip-in-iphone/25154308#25154308)

6.https://code.google.com/p/siphon/

7.http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/overview

8.https://code.google.com/p/idoubs/

Finally I got exact app what I expected is,,

9.http://www.portsip.com/downloads.html

I downloaded iOS project and run in simulator, exactly connecting with our asterisk server through SIP.
I can make call, incoming also.
But that is trail version. I unable to modify that code.

That connection link I unable to modify. Can any one guide me how to connect with server, when "REGISTER" button is click? Before pressing "REGISTER" button, I got Username, password, Server IP address in UITextfield.

Can anybody help me, how to register with SIP like in http://www.portsip.com/downloads.html ???

Answer (score 1):

For iOS i can recommend [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) from my own experience. I have created a callcenter application (for internal usage) and works fine and stable on iPhone and iPad. Just drag the source to XCode and it should compile with no issues and doesn't have further dependencies. They also have a good [tutorial](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone) for iOS.